# UICollectionView in UICollectionCell not showing Cells if there is any UI element in it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView with 3 sections. In each section I am displaying some data and have created separated xib files for each cell.
Second cell should show some kind a grid with several icons in it, 2 rows by 3 elements, so I decided to use CollectionView for that.

I decided to create CollectionViewController and include its view in second cell. (Code below is CollectionViewController for second cell)

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellItem", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellItem

    return cell
}
```

This is my "main" UICollectionView class

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // getting cell from first xib and returning it

        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        // This is second cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("secondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let tcv = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TCV") as! TrophiesCollectionViewController
        self.addChildViewController(tcv)
        tcv.view.frame = cell.bounds
        cell.addSubview(tcv.view)
        tcv.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        return cell
    }
    // Getting third cell from xib and returning it

}
```

Everything loads fine, even cells show if they are empty (tried that with different background colors). The problem starts when I add any UI element to second cell xib file, which causes whole section 2 not to show when I run the app. I am not even able to swipe to it, it doesn't even move.

Hope someone had any experience with this and could help. Thank you in advance!